# ID get NULL when i try to update data

Tags: oracle, plsql

I created stored procedure in Oracle SQL to update data in my table:

```sql
create or replace procedure UpdateProduct(product_id int
                                         ,product_name VARCHAR2
                                         ,product_price int
                                         ,product_description varchar2)
as
begin
  update product
     set name = product_name,
         price = product_price,
         description = product_description
   where id = product_id;
--
  insert into product(update_date)
  values (TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'DD.MM.YYYY hh24:mi:ss'));
end;
```

When I run the procedure, an error is thrown as the ID is NULL

```sql
begin
  UpdateProduct(26, 'шщйыа', 9845, 'ыгаз');
end;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you have that `insert` statement in the procedure? Are you trying to **update** the `update_date` in the same row? That's not what an `insert` does - `insert` inserts an entirely new row, which has nothing to do with the values you call the procedure with. Instead, add the assignment to `update_date` to the other assignments, in the `update` statement:

```
create or replace procedure UpdateProduct(product_id int
                                         ,product_name VARCHAR2
                                         ,product_price int
                                         ,product_description varchar2)
as
begin
  update product
     set name = product_name,
         price = product_price,
         description = product_description,
         update_date = TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'DD.MM.YYYY hh24:mi:ss')
   where id = product_id;
--
end;
```

As an aside, what is the data type of `update_date`? You are assigning a string to it. The data type should be `date` (in which case you should simply assign `SYSDATE` to it); the way you wrote it, either `update_date` is indeed of `date` data type, and then `TO_CHAR` is unnecessary (or, worse, it may cause problems), or `update_date` is of `varchar2` data type, which is in itself a huge mistake, which perhaps you can correct.

Comment: I need to write in update_date the time at which the data was updated in this procedure, the date should show hours, minutes, seconds. How can i do this?

Comment: @AlmatKaipzhanov the way you do that depends on the data type of `update_date`. Is it `DATE`, `TIMESTAMP`, `VARCHAR2`, something else?

Comment: @AlmatKaipzhanov - You need to understand that storing data and "showing" data are two different concepts. You store dates in `date` data type. What is **shown**, when you select the data for a report, depends on how you write the `select` query - you have full control over exactly what is shown (include hours, minutes and seconds if they are needed, or exclude them, or whatever). This has nothing to do with updating the data. On the other hand, the same things are still possible but much more complicated if the data type of the column is `varchar2`.

Comment: @AlmatKaipzhanov - Perhaps you come from a different database product, where `date` and `time` are distinct data types. In Oracle `date` always has both a date and a time-of-day component (even when you think it doesn't; a "pure date" actually does have a time, of 00:00:00). In Oracle you simply **can't** store a date "without time". Also, Oracle doesn't have a `time` data type (which is a problem sometimes). So, when you save `SYSDATE` in a column of `date` data type, the time of day is **always** stored, whether it is displayed or not!

Answer (score 0):

It is the insert that causes the error. You're trying to insert a line with update_date column filled only. Like that

| id | name | price | description | update_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| null | null | null | null | 01.01.2001 |

I assume the insert statement has to be at least like this:

```
insert into product(id, update_date)
values (some_id_goes_here, TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'DD.MM.YYYY hh24:mi:ss'));
```

Or maybe you need an update statement, I'm not sure what your logic is

Comment: my id is filled automatically with the help of a sequense, I used this in the previous procedure: create or replace NONEDITIONABLE procedure InsertProduct(product_name VARCHAR2, product_price int, product_description varchar2) as


begin

insert into PRODUCT(id, name, price, description, create_date) 
values(autoid.nextval, product_name, product_price, product_description, TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'DD.MM.YYYY hh24:mi:ss'));


end;